# Multiple image at once on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to upload multiple images at once but my API takes only one image among the list of images. What might be the reason for not taking all the images ? What have i done wrong?

Here's my code.
**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^api/', RentalList.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/upload/', FileUploadView.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', RentalDetail.as_view()),
```

**Models.py**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120,blank=True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Phone number of contact person"))
    listingName =  models.CharField(_("Lisitng Name"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Title of the rental space"))
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null= True,
        help_text=_("Description of the rental space"))
    property = models.CharField(_("Property type"),max_length=10,null=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False,null=True,
        help_text=_("Rental price of the space per month"))
    city =  models.CharField(_("City"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("City of the rental space"))
    place =  models.CharField(_("Place"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
        help_text=_("Place of the rental space"))
    phone_image = models.CharField(max_length=2048,blank=True,null=True,
        help_text=_("image form of the phone number"))
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='upload/',null=True,blank=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class RentalList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer
    queryset = Rental.objects.all()
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        rental = self.get_queryset()
        serializer_rental = RentalSerializer(rental,many=True)
        return Response(serializer_rental.data)

    @permission_classes((IsAdminUser, ))
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        user=request.user
        serializer_rental = RentalSerializer(data=request.data,context={'user':user})
        if serializer_rental.is_valid():
            serializer_rental.save()
            return Response(serializer_rental.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer_rental.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class RentalDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset=Rental.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RentalSerializer


class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['image']
        print('up_file is',uploaded_file)
        filename = '/media/upload'
        with open(filename, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
                print('chunk',chunk)
                destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()

        my_saved_file = open(filename)
        return Response(uploaded_file.name, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**registration.jsx**

```
var RenderPhotos = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
          files:[]
        };
    },

    onDrop(files) {
        console.log('Received files: ', files);
    this.setState({
        files: files
    });
    },

    showFiles() {
        const files = this.state.files || null;
        console.log('files',files);

        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        files.map((file, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                                    <img src={file.preview} width={100}/>
                                    <div>{file.name}</div>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },

    render: function () {
      return (
           <div>
                <h3>Photos can bring your space to life</h3>
                <p>Add photos of spaces to give more insight of your space </p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}
                          style={style}
                          activeStyle={activeStyle}>
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
              </form>
                {this.showFiles()}
                </div>
                <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep}>Back</button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works" onClick={this.submitRent}>Submit</button>
                </div>
          </div>
      );
    },

    submitRent: function(e) {
      // want to store the data so that when user reverts back to this form the data should be in same previous state 
      var req = request.post('http://localhost:8000/api/upload/');
      var image = [];
      image = new FormData();
      var that = this;
      var index;
      for (index = 0; index < that.state.files.length; ++index) {
          console.log(that.state.files[index]);
          image.append('image',that.state.files[index]);
      }
      req.send(image);
      console.log('req is',req);
      req.end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error', err);
        } else {
          console.log('success', res);

        }
      });
    }   
});
```

I have posted all the code thinking that it might be easy for tracing the errors.

Do i need to create ManyToMany field for image?

Comment: This is kind of a lot of code. The first thing I would do is try to figure out if the error is on the JS side or the Django side. Check out the request object in Django; is the API receiving all of the files and just not saving all of them, or is the client only sending one file? That will help you narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: It's a lot of totally unnecessary code as well. E g the `RentalSerializer.create` method does nothing that the base class `.create` doesn't.

Comment: Sorry for posting lots of code.Frontend correctly shows all the images but my FileUploadView function is not getting called when i try for tracking if the images have come or not.

Comment: +btmcnellis js shows all the files but print function inside fileuploadview class does not show the logs on django console.